# Smoothness of expectation

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations, brownian-motion

Suppose that $X_t$ is a strong solution to the SDE,
 $$dX_t = C_t \,dB_t$$ where $B_t$ is a standard Brownian motion and $C_t \ge 0$ is measurable with respect to the natural filtration generated by the Brownian motion.

Let $T > 0$ be a constant. Suppose $X_t = x \in (-1,1)$. Define, $\tau := \inf \{s \ge t: X_s \notin (-1,1)\} \wedge T$  and $$J(t,x) := \mathbb E \left[\int_t^\tau f(X_s, C_s) \, ds + h(\tau, X_\tau)\right].$$

I am interested in knowing what can be said about the smoothness of $J(\cdot, \cdot)$ in $t$ and $x$. In particular, if $f(x,c)$ is continuous in $x$ and u.s.c in $c$, and $h(t,x)$ is continuous in both the arguments, is $J(t,x)$ continuous in $t$ and usc in $x$? How about continuous in $x$?

Comment: The usual way to try to prove such statements is using the sequential definition of continuity and the dominated convergence theorem, or some form of uniform integrability.  If you want differentiability, try the "differentiation under the integral sign" lemma,

Answer (score 0):

First we apply [time change](https://almostsuremath.com/2010/04/20/time-changed-brownian-motion/) to write $X_{t}=x+B_{A_{t}}$ with $A_{t}:=\int_{0}^{t}C_{s}^{2}ds$ with inverse $g(s)=A^{-1}(s)$. So we have

$$\tau_{X,t}=t+\inf\{s\geq 0: B_{A_{s+t}}\in (-1-x,1-x)\}=t+\inf\{g(s)\geq t: B_{s}\in (-1-x,1-x)\},$$

and thus $\tau_{X,t}=t+g(T_{I,t})$ where $I:= (-1-x,1-x)$ and $T\geq A_{t}$ is the exit time from $I$ after time $A_{t}$.

So to get continuity in t,x, we use the continuity of the above processes eg. exit time $T_{I,t}$ is continuous using a reflection principle argument as here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3202704/derivation-of-joint-and-conditional-density-of-a-brownian-motion-and-its-maximum/3209052#3209052

For general dependence on parameters see here:
[Differentiable dependence on the initial condition of the solution of a SDE](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362570/differentiable-dependence-on-the-initial-condition-of-the-solution-of-a-sde/436132#436132)