# Reference to log-transition-density of a diffusion process

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

Consider the scalar diffusion $X=(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ given by

$$\mathrm{d}X_t \ = \ b(X_t)\,\mathrm{d}t \ + \ \sigma(X_t)\,\mathrm{d}B_t, \qquad X_0=\xi,$$

with $b$, $\sigma$ smooth, $\xi$ absolutely continuous and $B=(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ a standard Brownian motion (w.r.t. some prob. measure $\mathbb{P}$).

Suppose that the transition function $(t,x,\mathrm{d}y)\mapsto\mathbb{P}(X_t\in\mathrm{d}y\mid X_0=x)$ of $X$ admits a positive Lebesgue-density $\rho\equiv\rho(t,x,y)\in C^{1,2}(G)\cap C(\bar{G})$ with $G:=(0, T)\times\mathbb{R}^2$ for some  $T>0$.

I'm interested in (reasonable) conditions on $b$ and $\sigma$ which  guarantee that $D_T:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid \partial_x\, \partial_y\, \log(\rho(T,x,x))\neq 0\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

**Question:** Can you recommend any literature where the log-density $\log(\rho)$ of a general diffusion (of the above type) is analysed in enough detail to potentially derive (reasonable) sufficient conditions on $b$ and $\sigma$ for $D_T\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ to be dense?

Answer (score 1):

This question combines two different differentiable dependences. One for the initial condition see here:

[Differentiable dependence on the initial condition of the solution of a SDE](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/362570/differentiable-dependence-on-the-initial-condition-of-the-solution-of-a-sde/436132#436132)

and the other for the integration variable in the law of $X_{t}$, see theorem 2.3.3 in Nualart's Malliavin calculus and related topics:

[image]